# Gerber file analysing before production

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, altium, layout, board

I'm trying to check and analyze the PCBs of a board, developed with Ultium Designer before being produced. I already have the output files from Ultium Designer (it's not my job).

The output files contain the assembly drawing, BOM, test points, schematic_PDF, Pick Place, PDF3D, NC Drill, ODB, Gerber, ExportSTEP.
As I'm new to the analog side of electronics, I'd like to know how to analyze and verify these files before manufacturing to avoid any problems later on.

Is it possible to use Ultium Designer, or are there other specific programs?

I used Analysis/PCB Design Check/Fix, and I got some errors. I'm not sure I'm doing the right process. How can I do it for all the existing layers at the same time?

Comment: Analyze what exactly? It's common that you send the gerber and drill etc files to the PCB manufacturer, then they will take a look at it and give you feedback regarding the PCB manufacturing itself.

Comment: Then they assembly contractor may have different kind of feedback, such as if the panels are OK for production, if the components are grouped too tightly, if there are missing polarity markings etc etc. It's common to give the contractor whom you plan to use for production a prototype batch order, to get such feedback from them. And then you verify the assembled boards yourself and do a second board spin.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Like, the design is not mine, I want to check it first and to be sure that is well done and without errors before manufacturing, do you think is it the right why to do it or is it better to ask the manufacture to do it?

Comment: If it's the first board revision, it is rarely ever correct at first try, that's why we make prototypes. But as mentioned, there's 3 different kinds of expertise/review work involved: the design expertise which is the schematic + layout and has to be reviewed by electrical engineers (often in-house since this is the "intellectual property"), the PCB expertise which the manufacturer got and the assembly expertise which the assembly contractor got.

Comment: Well explained , thank you.

Comment: Ultium Designer?

Comment: yes, ultium designer.

Comment: Zero EDA search results on "ultium designer". _Altium_ designer however...

Comment: Hi, do you have any idea about the inverse process, please? If I have the output file, can I redesign the pcb and sch file to compile them and see the behave of the circuit before manufacturing? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Where I work, it's mandatory for *someone else* than the PCB designer to have a look at the Gerber files before being sent out to production. "Home blindness" does not translate well from Swedish, but it refers to if you look at your own design for long enough, you stop seeing your own mistakes. Imagine a picture frame hanging at an angle for the past ten years, you have long since stopped noticing and it's only when you have an engineer (preferably high on the autistic scale) visit you and points it out that you see it again.

Moreover, I recommend using *another* program to review it. Even if I do it myself, just the change in UI and colors means that you see it differently and your brain goes into review mode as opposed to design mode. GC prevue and ViewMate are popular programs to use.

Comment: So, here you are using human visualization to extract errors, or identify a design??

Comment: @khaoula Pretty much yes. With an ideal DRC, everything should be fine by the time you generate Gerbers. In reality, things are always missed.

Comment: how can I use the DRC with the gerber files? because I don't have the schematic design (.schdoc) files. thanks

Comment: @khaoula At Gerber level, 99 % of the information is lost and you can only check it manually for problems knowing what the PCBA is intended to do. You can however check if the PCB is manufacturable, which is what your PCB manufacturer does when they receive your files. They have no idea what your circuit is doing.

Comment: OK! thank you so much.

Comment: Hi @winny, do you have any idea about the inverse process, please? If I have the output file, can I redesign the pcb and sch file to compile them and see the behave of the circuit before manufacturing? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are commercial programs such as [CAM350](https://www.downstreamtech.com/) which are designed for this task- analyzing DFM, they are not free, but if you do this sort of thing a lot they should pay for themselves. I used an early version perhaps 20 years ago.

From memory, the higher end versions have features that were aimed at PCB manufacturing houses to handle things like acid traps, removing silk screen from pads and such like. Having this done silently by the PCB house is a two-edged sword, it means that your manufacturing documents are not being followed exactly, even though the results are (usually) better. This is trap when you're trying to maintain quality because there's no guarantee that another supplier (or that one) won't suddenly start following your documents exactly or will make changes that are not beneficial.

There are free Gerber preview programs that may well be enough since modern EDA tools follow design rules closely (but if those rules are set badly.. or exceptions are permitted..). Even without quantitative analysis of clearances etc. you can often find improvements by just 'eyeballing' the Gerbers of each layer.

Comment: thank you for your explanation, the case that I did the visual verification and it seems that it is OK, but I want to be sure that de whole  design with the different layers matches and there is no error like mass error or others...

Comment: Hi, do you have any idea about the inverse process, please? If I have the output file, can I redesign the pcb and sch file to compile them and see the behave of the circuit before manufacturing? thank you.

Comment: @khaoula In general it's not trivial at all to go backwards. It's reverse engineering, and might even require more skill than doing the design in the first place. Also the Gerbers don't have a lot of the information you'd need, they're just bare PCB fabrication files.

Comment: Even I have all the files, like schematic-pfd file, the manufacturing specification file all the data related to the fabrication, because I have to compile the design and validate it before prototyping (I planned to repeat the schematic pdf file to a schematic file and then to add all the used component to create the bcp and also the 3d one , using the same number of layers then to make a comparison between the two output files after validation )..., thanks.